# how do you split elements of a list of list in python?

Tags: python, list, split, strip

So I have a text file that looks like this:

```
abcd 
efghij
klm
```

and I need to convert it into a two-dimensional list. And it should look like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
['k', 'l', 'm']]
```

so far I have managed to get this result:

```
[["abcd"], ["efghij"], ["klm"]]
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the next step should be?
Here is my code so far:

```
def readMaze(filename):
    with open(filename) as textfile:
        global mazeList
        mazeList = [line.split() for line in textfile]
        print mazeList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a list  of each line in the file:

```
with open('tmp.txt') as f:
    z = [list(thing.strip()) for thing in f]
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>`str.split()` splits on whitespace. `str.split('')` splits each character separately.</strike> (apparently I'm misremembering, `str.split('')` throws a `ValueError` for `"empty separator"`)

You'll just build a `list` from it.

```
text = """abcd
efghij
klm"""

mazelist = [list(line) for line in text.splitlines()]
# the splitlines call just makes it work since it's a string not a file
print(mazelist)
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'm']]
```

Comment: It's giving me an attribute error - file object has no attribute 'splitlines'. Any tips?

Comment: @user3213742 as I mentioned in the comment RIGHT BELOW that line, I only used `splitlines` because I threw your text into a string instead of an object......... Files don't have a `splitlines` method, strings do.

Answer (score 1):

As explained above, you just need to build a list from the strings.

Assuming the string is held in some_text;

```
lines = some_text.split('\n')
my_list = []
for line in lines:
    line_split = list(line)
    my_list.append(line_split)
```

as one-liner;

```
my_list = map(lambda item: list(item), some_text.split('\n'))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: ```with open('file.txt') as f:``` , ```z = map(list, map(str.strip,f))``` , - might be better with map().